# Color intensity proportional to a number

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, colors

I have the following dataframe

```
> dataframe
 lx         rx   mc     
  6  58.340712    6
  6 -66.993792    0
 16  -7.163176    1
  4  43.801029    2
```

With:

```
>plot(dataframe$lx,dataframe$rx)
```

I obtain the plot of points `(6,58.340712)`, `(6,-66.993792)`, `(16,-7.163176)` and `(4,43.801029)`. I would like to color these points according to `mc` field. E.g., if `mc=0`, the point is black, otherwhise it is red. In addition, I would like the color intensity to be proportional to the value in `mc` field.

Comment: Add argument `col=dataframe$mc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Data**

```
d = structure(list(lx = c(6L, 6L, 16L, 4L),
                   rx = c(58.340712, -66.993792, -7.163176, 43.801029),
                   mc = c(6L, 0L, 1L, 2L)),
              class = "data.frame",
              row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

**Base**

```
#Figure out how many colors you need. If the minimum is 0, we need to add 1
#because indexing in R begins at 1.
n = max(d$mc) + (min(d$mc) == 0)

#Generate n colors based on your preference
cols = colorRampPalette(c("black", "red"))(n)

#Subset colors from 'cols' using values in d$mc
plot(d$lx, d$rx, col = cols[d$mc + (min(d$mc) == 0)], pch = as.character(d$mc), cex = 3)
```

[image]

**gglot**

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(lx, rx, col = mc)) +
    geom_point(size = 3) +
    scale_color_gradient(low = "black", high = "red")
```

[image]